# Wordpress custom meta information

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a WP website and I'm using Yoast SEO plugin. However, I cant find the code to go in the header.php that will grab the custom meta info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the wp_head action hook on your header.php file

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```